# Android Studio - auto generate variables by xml file ID-s

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout, code-generation

Can Android Studio Layout Designer auto-generate variables from xml(layout) source code like this tool? 
[Android variables generator from xml layout source code](http://android.okhelp.cz/get-all-id-from-xml-file-for-android-developers-utility/)

[image: Android variables generator by xml layout source code]

Answer (score 0):

No, it only designed layout and you can create variable and map these variable with source one